# Is interesting activity on cstheory.stackexchange.com decreasing over the last year or so?

Tags: discussion

**[2016]:** I have the subjective impression that the rate at which interesting questions and answers are being posted on cstheory.stackexchange.com has decreased substantially over the last year or so.  Does anybody else have this impression (maybe answer that in a comment)?  Or even better, does anyone have access to cstheory.stackexchange.com metadata to check this trend objectively?

**[August 2018]:** *Moved the data that had accumulated here down into a community-wiki answer, and posted updated data suggesting that, as of 2018, the downward trend seems to be continuing (see chart at end of post).*

Comment: Most of metadata is online and can be queried: [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: A comparison with Math Overflow and Computer Science might be useful. There is also the issue of new more specialized sites like [crypto.se].

Comment: I know several grad students who like cstheory but feel uncomfortable to ask questions,, they feel their questions are not good enough. I have tried to convince them to give it a try but haven't been very successful. They seem afraid to ask questions that might look silly or trivial and it is very difficult to convince them it is OK, you don't need to have an extraordinary good question to ask. We may need to do something more proactive about it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't have data for earlier years. There seems to be a similar decline on [Mathoverflow.se] as well. It would be interesting to see if there is a decline also in the amount of visits, I will write a query for that next week if someone doesn't do it by then.

Comment: It's too bad. I used to stop by the site every few months to look for interesting questions and answers and would usually find a few new ones.  Now, not so much.

Comment: What happened in November 2014?

Comment: I do think that "perceived reputational risk adversion" may be at work. Perhaps it would be good to encourage members to be more accepting of imperfection. E.g. rather than "this is a bad question" ... comment "did you mean to ask..." when its possible to discern. Also I notice that perfectly good answers are often put into comments, perhaps because author doesn't believe what they wrote is canonical.

Comment: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2876/

Comment: An interesting point: the older posts are more likely to have higher total vote count, one has to take that into account when doing the comparison. We have one of the highest number of votes per post, that might be contributing to the fact that we have a steeper slope. It would be interesting to count only votes on posts for a fixed time period after they are posted, e.g. 30 days.

Comment: excellent quantitative analysis, thx! think SE should provide these basic engagement stats across sites but they are not much available. mods can see site hits which is generally more what SE mgt cares about. there are some rumors of SE-wide slow declines in voting etc.; this may even be a general property of social media sites in general eg wikipedia, and facebook has also noted "status update" decline. however, have long advocated spicing up this site and broadening the charter in various ways to little avail, site mentality is conservative. suggest/ encourage further discussion in [chat]

Comment: I also got the data for older posts: http://data.stackexchange.com/cstheory/query/490846/?points=60&period=30&upvoteWindow=30#graph

Comment: How about we make the EDIT 1-5 parts into an answer?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen: Ok, good idea.

Comment: @Kaveh Do you still experience people being reluctant to post on [cstheory.SE]? Any luck pointing them to [cs.SE]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Both *interesting* and *overall* activity on cstheory are decreasing!

Let's measure "interesting" activity by the rate of posts that receive significant upvotes.  By this measure, Figure 1 below suggests that both interesting activity and overall activity are trending downward:

[image]

> Figure 1. Above are plots (over time, in 60-day blocks), of (a) number of questions, (b) number of answers, (c) # upvotes / 20, (d) number of questions and answers that received at least five (or at least ten, for (e)) upvotes within 30 days of creation, on cstheory.stackexchange.com.

All trend downward. (The query that generated the data is [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/cstheory/query/889763/activity-over-time?points=46&period=60&upvoteWindow=30#graph).)

---

### The same plots on other stackexchange sites, for comparison

#### cs.stackexchange.com

[image]

#### crypto.stackexchange.com

[image]

#### math.stackexchange.com

[image]

#### tex.stackexchange.com

### [image]